# Por que o JavaScript não está mostrando o número de casa decimais?

Tags: javascript, formatação

O exemplo abaixo amostra normalmente o dois zero:

```js
console.log(100);
```

Mas ao colocar uma casa decimal ou mais ele não mostra:

```js
console.log(100.000);
```

Comment: Decimais apenas com 0 é ignorado. Teria que usar `100.000.toFixed(3)`. Só que o `.toFixed()` converte o número em string.

Comment: @Sam, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Porque você não mandou mostrar. Um erro comum que as pessoas cometem é achar que o que está vendo são números. Nada que você entra ou manda sair de uma aplicação para um humano manipular são números de fato.

Há uma ambiguidade disso que convivemos na matemática (escrevemos no papel quando calculamos algo um texto que representa números e passamos a vida toda achando que aquilo é um número, mas não é, ali tem apenas a representação do número), mas em computador é necessário ser mais preciso nas definições.

O número existe por si só, você não o vê, ele é uma abstração. Para ver o número é preciso achar a **representação textual** dele, que é algo mais concreto. E você está falando dessa representação.

Quando manda imprimir algo que é numérico a biblioteca do JS internamente faz uma conversão de um número para um texto e é isto que você vê. A forma padrão da linguagem é fazer isto no formato mais simples que puder. Então o número que nós conhecemos como 100 será impressão como o texto `"100"`, não importa como você digitou ele no código, ele é só o número 100, e quando você digita no código está colocando o número, não o que você está vendo ali, o compilador converte este texto em número.

Lembra da matemática? Zeros à esquerda antes da parte decimal e zeros à direta na parte decimal não tem relevância, então 100.000 não existe como número, só existe 100. Existe a representação textual "100.000". E quando manda imprimir só imprime o que existe de fato que é o 100.

Se deseja forçar um formato específico para a representação textual do número então tem que dizer isso no código na hora de imprimir de forma explícita como quer. Pode ser assim:

```js
console.log(100..toFixed(3));
```

Note que nem precisa usar o número com as casas porque como já foi dito esses zeros depois da vírgula não tem relevância.

É importante perceber que esta função [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) retorna um texto e não um número, por isso que você vê as casas decimais colocadas.

Tive que usar `..`, o primeiro ponto é para finalizar o número e tornar não ambíguo que depois vem um ponto do método a ser aplicado. Poderia ter escrito assim:

```
console.log(100.0.toFixed(3));
```

Ou:

```
console.log((100).toFixed(3));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/NumberLiteral.js).

Se fosse uma variável não teria esse problema porque não fica ambíguo, é só uma questão de sintaxe do JS.

Comment: obrigado muito bem explicado!